# Free and easy way to dynamically update/send text to released app via internet?

Tags: ios, web-services, twitter, nsurlsession

I would like to be able to send text to/update a Label in my App that is already released whenever I want to via Internet. It really just needs to be a little text, like one or two sentances.

I was doing a lot of research on how to achieve this.

Twitter - use a Twitter Account to post the text and get the post from inside the app ? - Just found solutions to read the user Account that is currently using the app (but should be my own account where i can post, and that post should be shown in the app to everybody) and need to be locked in Twitter in System preferences. If you want to read "foreign" account you need to integrate fabric - sign there... very complicated... !?

Podcast ?

Just get text from anywhere via NSURLSession - I have no Website to put the text on... !?

Use Restful Service ? Is there any free web service I can just write two sentences and they could get loaded into my app?

So I am not asking about how to implement NSURLSession or so, I just wonder what would be the easiest and free way to provide text somewhere in some format from where my app could download the text and update a label? I don t really want to pay for a service or a website just to write two sentances from time to time, from where I could download it into my app...

Thanks for ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to put a text file in a Github repo. Github provides a link to the raw file, so your app could pull from that URL.

If you want to do this through the web interface, you can follow these steps:

1. Create an account on github.com, and log in.
2. Click the plus (+) in the upper right to add a new repository.
3. Pick any name for "Repository name".
4. Check "Initialize this repository with a README".  You need this to make it easy to edit online.
5. Click the green "Create repository" button.
6. Click "Create new file".
7. Fill in the file name.
8. Enter whatever text you want for your app in the body of the file.
9. Click the green "Commit" button at the bottom.

Whenever you want to edit the file, you can click on the file name and then click the pencil to edit it.

You can get the link to the file by clicking the "Raw" button (when viewing the file) and copying the URL from your URL bar.  It should be something like `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo>/blob/master/<filename>`.

Comment: thx, I am not familiar with Github, was hoping for a "really easy free solution" ;)

Comment: Oh sure, sorry about that.  I've added step-by-step instructions that will hopefully make it easier.  Github is really powerful and can do a lot more than this, but if all you want to do is host a text file, its web UI works just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that sounds not too complicated indeed ;) To show the text in my app, will I have to download the file, or can my app read it? What would the code be in Objective-C ? So what is the "address" of Github?

Comment: Cool thanks, so I will download the whole file? Not read it with REST commands or something like this?

Comment: Oh sorry that was an important detail!  I've added info about how to get a link to your file.  I'm not sure what you mean about download vs read.

Comment: You can also read it with REST.  An HTTP GET to that URL will fetch the contents of the file.

Comment: Ok thank, it will be easier to just read it with GET instead of downloading and and overwriting older version and so pn... Thanks a lot, this sounds easy and implementable ;)

Comment: very good solution, got it working very quickly and easily ! THX